# Error in file(file, "rt") - Coursera R Programming Week 2 Assignment 1

Tags: r, path, connection, rstudio, data-analysis

I am doing the following assignment:
[Coursera Air pollution Assignment][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAcMG.png
After doing dir.create("specdata") and unzipping the file, all 332 files went to the "specdata" directory. So I did the function:

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id = 1:332) {
    lista <- list.files("C:/Users/Ana/Desktop/Temporario/specdata", pattern = "*.csv")

    for(i in id) {
            dados <- read.csv(lista[i])
            valor <- numeric(dados[pollutant])
    }
    mean(valor, na.rm = TRUE)
```

}

And as I tested it with

```
pollutantmean("specdata", "sulfate", 1:10)
```

I got the error message:

> Error in file(file, "rt") : not possible to open the connection
> Warning message: In file(file, "rt") :

Could anyone help? When I list.files they all appear (001.csv, ..., 332.csv), and my working directory is the parent environment to "specdata".

Comment: `*` and `.` are meta-characters, try escaping them: `pattern = "\\*\\.csv$"`. In my experience, you don't need the asterisk, put the dollar sign at the end instead.

Comment: Also, add `list.files(..., full.names=TRUE)`, since otherwise the filenames are just files, not the directory paths leading up to them.

Comment: Thank you both very much for the suggestions! But when doing the \\*\\ suggestion the error message was: _Error in file(file, "rt"): 'description' argument invalid_. And when setting `full.names = TRUE`, the error message was: _Error in numeric(dados[pollutant]): argument 'length' invalid_